# Create ZF 2 Forms from Doctrine Entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

What I want to know is the best way to create a form which matches an entity.

- Manually Create the form either in code or using the form annotations?
- Using Annotations from the entity?

I've see a few different examples, some using @Annotation and others using @Form? Could somebody please explain the difference?

In the case of entities having related/nested entities do I need to provide a custom hydrator for every entity? I'm presuming Doctrine may already have one that implements the hydrator interfaces?

To Summarise:
  - Best way to create a form from an Entity.
  - Difference between @Form and @Annotation
  - Does Doctrine have a Hydrator for it's Entities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off: Annotations are a Speed-Killer. If you want to use the annotation builder, please ALWAYS Cache the created objects. But annotations are also the easiest way to get a form running ;)

Second: The Hydrator. When using ZF2 Forms in conjunction with Doctrine 2 you most likely want to use the DoctrineEntity Hydrator located inside. Consider the following code:

```
$form = new ReferenzwertForm();
$form->setHydrator(new DoctrineEntity($serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')))
     ->setObject(new Referenzwert())
     ->setInputFilter(new ReferenzwertFilter())
     ->setAttribute('method', 'post');
return $form;
```

- ReferenzwertForm() is of type `Zend\Form\Form Object`
- DoctrineEntity() is of type `DoctrineORMModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineEntity`

  - DoctrineEntity needs the EntityManager provided. You should be familiar with this when using Doctrine 2 in ZF2
- Referenzwert() is a Entity-Object

When not using annotations and you're referencing another Entity, then make sure you use the appropriate form element (in most cases this would be a select-element (like selecting a CategoryEntity for a BlogEntity or something)

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'type',
    'type' => 'DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\DoctrineEntity',
    'options' => array(
          'label' => 'Choose a MyEntity',
          'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
          'target_class' => 'Namespace\Entity\MyEntity',
          'property' => 'name'
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'required' => true
    )
));
```

As you can see, the Form element needs to know about the entityManager, too. This is why ideally you'd want to extend the first Code-Example with another setter to inject the entityManager into your form object.

```
$form->setEntityManager($serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'))
     ->set()//all the other stuff
```

What's the best approach in general? I'd say there is none. For speed purposes, annotations solely are a killer. Using cached versions should help out, though i have no personal experience with caching in ZF2 just yet. I like to create my forms from hand outside of annotations, simply because my IDE supports a lot of stuff, but certainly not form annotations :D

Hope this could help you a bit and i didn't write too much out of context :P

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Would I be correct in presuming that your code example with the target_class etc could be converted to Annotations? I don't feel as though performance will be a major issue in these areas and caching is something we can implement if need be.

Comment: I haven't worked with annotations so far, so i can't tell you exactly. What i know is that parsing is a huge performance draw, therefore i stepped away from it. It's enough to me of having the entities parsed already ;) `target_class` defines the entity to be displayed and `property` is the property that's displayed inside select-element

Comment: I don't feel as though the performance hit is negligible on forms. Do you have some evidence of this? Otherwise your code sample worked great. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I ran some personal benchmarks, yes. But other than that, annotations work via string-parsing and regular expressions. Not exactly what you'd call 'speedy' stuff in PHP ;)

Comment: With the dev toolbar this is what I currently experienced: Before I used Doctrine: 150ms. Added Doctrine2 with Annotations: 300ms. Added cache adapter to Doctrine2 (just renamed array to memcached and added instance): 200ms. So adding doctrine added about 50ms and reduced the code I needed by about 90% :P This is on development system as well so...

Comment: I implement this example in my project. But this is not working in "editAction". My mean when i choose another option from select in editForm then doctrine loose track of changing in nested object. How can i solve this problem ?